# If a PHP variable is empty, return nothing; and if it's not empty return it with brackets around it

Tags: php, variables

I'm struggling with a form I've built and need some help from you good people out there. I've tried a few techniques using my extremely basic knowledge of arrays and the implode and empty functions but I'm still stuck...

This is a basic version of the HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="os_used" class="radio" value="windows" />
<input type="radio" name="os_used" class="radio" value="mac" />
<input type="radio" name="os_used" class="radio" value="other" />
<input type="text" name="os_name" class="text" />
```

And this is the PHP that uses the above HTML:

```
$os_used = $_REQUEST["os_used"] ;
$os_name = $_REQUEST["os_name"] ;
$message = "operating system: $os_used ($os_name)" ;
```

The message is then sent to my email address.

On the form, if the input named 'other' is selected, the 'os_name' text box appears, prompting the user to specify which operating system they use. This is then returned on an email that I'm sent once the form is submitted. The only problem is, 99% of the time, the 'other_os' won't be selected and I'll get this on the email: 'operating system: mac ()' or 'operating system: windows ()'. So I'd only like the brackets to appear if the 'other' radio button is selected, returning something like this 'operating system: other (linux)' and the brackets wouldn't be there if 'mac' or 'windows' were selected.

So my thinking is that the brackets would have to be concatenated either side of the $os_name variable and set as a variable in themselves that would only appear on the condition that $os_name had any kind of value entered into it on the form. I'm stumped!

Thanks for your time,

Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

()= Parenthesis.
[]= Brackets.
An important distinction.

```
$message = "Operating System: $os_used ";
if ($os_name!="") $message.="($os_name)";
```

Comment: for the nerd programmer and unreadable code maker: $message .= ($os_name!="")?"($os_name)":"";

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below.

```
$os_used = $_REQUEST["os_used"] ;
$os_name = $_REQUEST["os_name"] ;

if ($os_name) {
    $message = "operating system: other ($os_name)";
} else {
    $message = "operating system: $os_used";
}
```

Comment: In line 4 I think that should be `if ($os_name) {`

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to check that it's not just whitespace, for which you can use trim().

`$formatted_os = trim($os_name)? '('.$os_name.')' : '';`

Just stick that in after you pull in the `$_REQUEST['os_name']` and before the message is created.  Optionally instead of using the second variable `$formatted_os` you could just overwrite `$os_name`.

Comment: Would this be the way to overwrite $os_name: $os_name = trim($os_name)? '('.$os_name.')' : '';

Comment: Yes indeed.  As ITroubs mentioned, this is using the ternary operator: http://www.addedbytes.com/lab/ternary-conditionals/ an inline replacement for if-then-else.  Use it sparingly, it's easy to make your code unreadable if you use it too much.

Comment: Thanks Tchalvak (and ITroubs)!